# Proving a limit using the formal definition of a limit

Tags: analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove by using the formal definition of limit that:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty  }\dfrac{1}{x^4 + x^2 + 5} = 0$

Can anyone please lend a hand here?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*
$$
\frac{1}{x^4+x^2+5} \le \frac{1}{x^2}\le \epsilon,
$$
whenever $x > \sqrt{1/\epsilon}$.